# How can I make Clean URLs from HTML Files using RewriteRules?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.html [NC]
```

I have html pages in that `folder` and I want the files to serve other pages. eg:

`/folder/about` should serve `/folder/about.html`

`/folder/test` should serve `/folder/test.html`

The question is that the above rewrite script give me a 500 internal error. How do I achieve what I want to do?

EDIT:

I see this error in the error log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: What is the other page that mod rewrite is showing?

Comment: what do you mean? /folder/about should see content from /folder/about.html

Comment: What is happening when you try viewing these rewrite rules?

Comment: Basically... what is your question? :)

Comment: edited my question. The htaccess script basically doesn't work

Comment: Added an answer below; it validates on Lyxx, at least: (http://www.lyxx.com/freestuff/002.html).

Comment: Updated my answer after I saw your internal redirect error; it could be a slash issue (@Olivier Pons) with RewriteBase, if that answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a slash problem. Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond $1 !\.html$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

If it doesn't work try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder
RewriteCond $1 !\.html$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you want to change only letters and numbers (e.g. `wwW.site.com/abdd0456` but **not** `www.site.com/afdf/sdqfsd`) then do something like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond $1 !\.html$
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) $1.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

[Edit: add the `L` directive]

Comment: Olivier, your rule works but for the wrong reasons.  The OPs queries are doing an internal redirect and generating `about.html.html.html...` etc.  Thorpe just needs to add a `RewriteCond $1 !\.html$` before the rule

Comment: Ok, you're right. And maybe add the **`L`** = 'Last rewrite' condition... updated my answer.